# Python - Code Query

Tags: python

[image]

When I type the following code through command prompt in python, I get an error.
When I type the same in Atom and run via script, the code runs.
Can anyone advise what could be a problem here. Thanks.

[image]

Code:

```
city = 'kolkatta'
count = 0
for blah in city:
    if blah=='l'
        count=count+1
print (count)
```

Comment: try to  insert empty line before print, and better put your code as text formated

Comment: Could you copy/paste what you typed in the prompt? Indentation problem is the most common in these cases, but a simple copy/paste will do for us to show you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to insert an empty line after `count=count+1`.

> Continuation lines are needed when entering a multi-line construct. As
>   an example, take a look at this if statement:...

from [2.1.2. Interactive Mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode)